# Doom emacs org-agenda does not show to do items

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, emacsclient, doom

I am new to doom emacs, I am trying to give a shot to using org mode todos and agenda files. I created a sample org file with a list of to-do items as below.

```
#+TITLE: Sample list

* Check
** TODO Item 1
** TODO Item 2
** TODO Item 3
** TODO Item 4
```

After saving this file, when I check the agenda view by doing `SPC o a t` in doom emacs, I do not see any of these todos listed in there.

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Press ‘N r’ (e.g. ‘0 r’) to search again: (0)[ALL]
```

Below is my config settings relating to org directory.

```
(setq org-directory "~/notes/")
```

Can anyone help me with what settings I might be missing here for the agenda view to work properly?

Comment: You need to add the file to your `org-agenda-files`: not sure of the Doom binding, but in normal Emacs it is `C-c [` bound to `org-agenda-file-to-front`. `org-directory` does not have any special meaning to Org mode. If you are expecting to add to the agenda list all the files in that directory, read the doc string of the variable `org-agenda-files`.

Comment: I was wrong about `org-directory`: it does have a special meaning in Org mode, but not the one you seem to be expecting. After you do `C-h v org-agenda-files`, then do `C-h v org-directory` to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you @NickD, I am now able to see the agenda todo items after adding the current file using `org-agenda-file-to-front`.

Comment: Also setting the `org-agenda-files` to the entire directory lists all TODOs. Thank you !